# Printing an app's view?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is there a way to print slots/elements or an entire window under Shoes?

By this, I mean to direct output to the default system printer?

Thanks!

JP

Answer (score 1):

Shoes doesn't support anything of the sort at present, and there's a good chance it never will.  _why says that the purpose of Shoes isn't to develop business apps; it's intended more to teach/encourage new programmers.  Plus, he's already concerned with how big the codebase has become.

While it's still possible it could be added later, there is just so much else that is considered more pressing.  At least for now, you'll have better luck trying QtRuby or wxRuby or JRuby.

Comment: Correct, there is no built in printing. However, ashbb has discovered a hidden 'snapshot' screen printing feature. See here: http://github.com/ashbb/shoes_hack_note/blob/master/md/hack018.md